how define my logger function from macros
I have an header file for logging comming froma static library, I don't have access to the source code of the library just header.
I like their way of debug, I'd like to create my owm debug file by being inspired by their way of doing things
Here is the header file
#ifndef _LOGGER_H
#define _LOGGER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef enum {
    LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR = 0, 
    LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_WARN = 1,
    LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_INFO = 2,
    LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG = 3, 
} E_LoggerConsoleLogLevel;

#define USER_LOG_DEBUG(fmt, ...)    \
        Logger_UserLogOutput(LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "[%s:%d) " fmt, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__ , ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define USER_LOG_INFO(fmt, ...)     \
        Logger_UserLogOutput(LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "[%s:%d) " fmt, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__ , ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define USER_LOG_WARN(fmt, ...)     \
        Logger_UserLogOutput(LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_WARN, "[%s:%d) " fmt, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__ , ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define USER_LOG_ERROR(fmt, ...)    \
        Logger_UserLogOutput(LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "[%s:%d) " fmt, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__ , ##__VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

If I understand well I have to declare my function Logger_UserLogOutput(E_LoggerConsoleLogLevel  level,...)but I don't know what I have to put in argument afet levelwhat is fmt?
For example I want to do something like that USER_LOG_DEBUG("debug msg");and have something like this in my serial termial : [DEBUG] function:line : debug msg
EDIT : void Logger_UserLogOutput(E_LoggerConsoleLogLevel level,const char *fmt, ...)is my prototype
but if I try to print value like :
printf("[DEBUG] %s\n"); I always got [DEBUG] [%s:%d) debug msg why ?

fmt should be the (printf style) format specifier for the variable arguments (if none present, it could be the empty string). Maybe https://github.com/Kurento/gstreamer/blob/master/gst/gstinfo.h would help.

Consider whether there's any useful information in #define macro for debug printing in C?

It's hard to see why the header shown did not include a declaration for Logger_UserLogOutput().  It's also odd that the "[%s: %d)" argument is passed uniformly — arguments should be for things that differ between calls to the function.  The , ## __VA_ARGS__ notation is a GCC extension to the C standard.  C23 provides an alternative, better way to handle that — the __VA_OPT__(…) mechanism that's also in C++20.

You can define your own variadic functions by using the va_ macros from stdarg.h. You can also pass a variadic argument list to functions like vprintf to print a format string. Example:
#include <stdarg.h>

void Logger_UserLogOutput(E_LoggerConsoleLogLevel level, const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;

    if(level == LOGGER_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG) {
        printf("[DEBUG] ");
    }
    // code for other levels…

    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    printf("\n");
}


These are wrappers for a printf-like function where fmt is the format string and they allow a variable amount of arguments too, like printf. So if you want to write a function to accept that input, it has to be a variadic one with the features from stdarg.h (variadic functions are generally not recommended).
These macros assume that fmt is a string literal and concatenates it with the string literal "[%s:%d) ". In addition, ##__VA_ARGS__ is a non-standard compiler extension to swallow up empty argument lists - it is not standard C.
__FUNCTION__ is not standard C either but an old GNU C remain from the 1990s. Since C99 we can use ISO C __func__ so that's what we should be doing.
If you don't need all of this somewhat over-engineered flexibility but just print strings, you could just do a light version of it:
#define USER_LOG_ERROR(str) printf("%s %s() line %d: %s\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, str)

Example:
#include <stdio.h>

#define USER_LOG_ERROR(str) printf("%s %s() line %d: %s\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, str)

int main (void)
{
  USER_LOG_ERROR("bad stuff happened");
}

Output:
/app/example.c main() line 7: bad stuff happened


Ok thanks @Lundin and if I want to do my printf in my function Logger_UserLogOutputwith this protype Logger_UserLogOutput(E_LoggerConsoleLogLevel level, const char *fmt, ...) is possible ? Should I have to do printf("%s", fmt)?

@simon As mentioned in this answer fmt is the format string. As in printf("%s", str), the "%s" part is the format string. It only makes sense to pass along that to your debug function if you wish custom formatting and a variable number of arguments in the same manner as printf.

@simon: Typically, the implementation of the logging function will use vprintf(), vfprintf() or vsprintf() because the variables arguments have to be identified by a va_list (see <stdarg.h>).  And it is frequently most sensible to write the debug information to either stderr or a file, so you're less likely to use vprintf() than the other functions.
